# Sending hex as byte to a printer

Tags: java, android, printing

I'm trying to write to a Brother label printer, even Brother supplies a SDK they do not have a newsroom for developers and the support are send to the regular printer support.

I have to send the following hex 1b, 69, 7a, 84, 00 as one of many lines.

I tried to do the following but I get an error on the hex 84 saying not a byte. I did a print to file from Brothers label program to view it in a hex editor and the hex editor shows 1B 69 7A 84 00

```
final ArrayList<Byte> commands = new ArrayList<Byte>();
Byte[] printinfoCommand = new Byte[] {0x1b, 0x69, 0x7a, 0x84, 0x00];
AddRange(commands, printinfoCommand);
byte[] commandToSendToPrinter = convertFromListByteArrayTobyteArray(commands);
myPrinter.writeBytes(commandToSendToPrinter);

public static void AddRange(ArrayList<Byte> array, Byte[] newData) {
    for(int index=0; index<newData.length; index++) {
        array.add(newData[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `0x84` is not a byte have you tried as `(byte)0x84` ?

Comment: Try to change Byte to byte. byte is primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you need to send a `byte[]` to the printer interface.  With that in mind, there's a couple of issues with your code.

Firstly, you're using an array of big B `Byte` (which is the [wrapper object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html)), rather than an array of primitive `byte`s.

Secondly, in Java a `byte` is signed, so the maximum literal `byte` you can write (without casting) is `0x7F`.  To specify a `byte` of `0x84`, you'll have to explicitly cast it.

Your array literal should therefore be:

```
byte[] printInfoCommand = 
    new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x69, 0x7a, (byte) 0x84, 0x00 };
```

and you can pass this array:

```
myPrinter.writeBytes(printInfoCommand);
```

The other lines of code you have look unnecessary.

Comment: I have to look again but when I tried to cast (byte) 0x84 I made a breakpoint to see what the printInfoCommand contained and in the LogCat it show as decimal value of -125

Comment: `-124` actually. As mentioned, Java bytes are signed. `0x84` is `0b10000100` - you can see that the sign bit is set.  `0x84` when expressed as a signed byte, printed in decimal is `-124`.

Comment: What confused me is that hex 84 is decimal 132. My problem is that the printer is not printing and when I saw the -124 instead of 132 i thought the wrong byte was send to the printer resulting in no print. When I look at the hex editor of the print file I captured and change the view to binary I do get 1000100 but if I view as decimal i get 132. So I understand that Android Studio shows it as -124